# How to do a simple calculation in an DAX AVERAGE function?

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

My goal was a simple calculation inside my `AVERAGE` Statement in PowerBi. The value `Einheitsvalue` can range from 1 to 5 and I wanted to subtract it from 6 ( `6 - Einheitsvalue` ) to get a inverse value.

[image: DAX Statement]

In my PowerBi Statement it looked something like that.

`AVERAGE( ( 6 - CALCULATE_DATA_PI[Einheitsvalue] ) )`

but it didn't work. I also tried the `AVERAGEX` function without any results.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucas, the Syntax for `AVERAGE()` is

```
AVERAGE(<column>)
```

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/average-function-dax,
so it doesn't accept an `<expression>`.

But you can transform your "simple calculation" into

```
6 - AVERAGE( CALCULATE_DATA_PI[Einheitsvalue] )
```

which is mathematically the same thing. Of cause this works inside `SUMMARIZE()` too. Was this your question?

Comment: Thank you, i never considerd to do the calculation outside the function.